# Memory Errors when diagonalizing very large sparse python arrays

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

For a research project that I am doing, I am diagonalizing huge (10^6 x 10^6) sparse, Hermitian matrices using scipy.sparse's eigsh function. When I run the program, I get a memory error that says "can't allocate region" "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug." I don't really know what this means and I was trying to figure it out. I was hoping to get some information on this error and some suggestions to (hopefully) fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't comment on your code if we can't see what you're doing. Also, please add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting while running the MCVE.

Comment: Without further information, the generic answer is that MemoryError means you do not have enough memory to do the operation you are trying to do. The solution is to either get more memory, or ensure you are using 64-bit versions of all libraries. Another possibility is that what you are trying to do is not even in principle possible with current computers.